# How to get a device file name using major and minor number

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying add some debug messages in block io to track the io operation in linux kernel.

IO could happen to multiple block device, I have `dev_t` value with me.

I can get major and minor number from `dev_t`.

I want to know is there any way to get the device file name from `/dev/` dir using these major and minor number?

Of course, I need kernel APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple:

1. Use [bdget](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2047) function to find the `block_device` by `dev_t`.
2. Use [bdevname](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2142) to get the device name.
3. Use [bdput](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2051) to put the device reference.

Have fun.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in userspace?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `libudev`. Since you already have the `dev_t` id this way is aesier.

```
#include <libudev.h>

// Create the udev context.
struct udev *udev = udev_new();

// Create de udev_device from the dev_t.
struct udev_device *dev = udev_device_new_from_devnum(udev, 'b', sb.st_dev);

// Finally obtain the node.
const char* node  = udev_device_get_devnode(dev);

udev_unref(udev);
```

Comment: Note that `libudev` is an userspace library, while OP is working in kernel space and therefore explicitly asks for *kernel* APIs, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot do such simple reverse mapping. This is because knowing some major and major numbers, one can always use `mknod` to create valid device file anywhere, not necessarily under `/dev`.

At the end of the day, kernel does not care much how did any particular device node with certain major/minor came about - such a node is simply entry point into the kernel device driver that can handle this hardware or software device.

Granted, in practice on most modern Linux systems most device nodes are located in `/dev` and maintained by `udev` - but it is user-space daemon, which your kernel driver cannot talk to. Also note that `udev` can be configured to create new device nodes with any name.